# Pgfplots: Draw time-series without missing data

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, ticks, dateplot

I have time-series data which I want to draw with pgfplots. The data only covers weekdays, thus no weekends. Still pgfplots inserts new ticks for datapoints having essentially no data, this results in "empty areas" at the weekends within the chart (see below). Is there any possibility to change this behavior so that these empty ticks are not generated?[image]

mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe.csv}
Date,a,b
2008-01-02 00:00,15847.5,3784
2008-01-03 00:00,19345.5,5761.5
2008-01-04 00:00,20055,5611.5
2008-01-07 00:00,18907.5,4608.5
2008-01-08 00:00,20613.5,5155.5
2008-01-09 00:00,22102,4956.5
2008-01-10 00:00,23949,5034
2008-01-11 00:00,15518,4168.5
2008-01-14 00:00,19858,5504
2008-01-15 00:00,26947,7926
2008-01-16 00:00,24994,6592.5
2008-01-17 00:00,27077.5,6529.5
2008-01-18 00:00,38022.5,10623.5
2008-01-21 00:00,45479,12335
2008-01-22 00:00,38043,10338.5
2008-01-23 00:00,27517.5,7620
2008-01-24 00:00,29803.5,5838.5
2008-01-25 00:00,32695.5,4921
2008-01-28 00:00,19122,5384
2008-01-29 00:00,16761.5,3976.5
2008-01-30 00:00,19546,5519.5
2008-01-31 00:00,21879.5,5624.5
2008-02-01 00:00,15205,4113
2008-02-04 00:00,23555.5,5067.5
2008-02-05 00:00,27960.5,5217.5
2008-02-06 00:00,31158,5738.5
2008-02-07 00:00,24475,4778.5
2008-02-08 00:00,22286,4697
2008-02-11 00:00,22962,5735
2008-02-12 00:00,21080,4979
2008-02-13 00:00,19351.5,4378.5
2008-02-14 00:00,20144,4555.5
2008-02-15 00:00,13511,2853.5
2008-02-18 00:00,19149.5,4604.5
2008-02-19 00:00,22329,4072.5
2008-02-20 00:00,18542.5,3991
2008-02-21 00:00,23080.5,4690
2008-02-22 00:00,18790,3574.5
2008-02-25 00:00,21891.5,5164
2008-02-26 00:00,20662.5,4645.5
2008-02-27 00:00,21164,4491.5
2008-02-28 00:00,24220,4372
2008-02-29 00:00,22114.5,4449.5
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
date coordinates in=x, 
xticklabel={\begin{turn}{45}\day.\month.\year \end{turn}\\},
x tick label style={align=center},
ymajorgrids,
xmin={2008-01-01 00:00},
xmax={2008-02-20 22:00},
ymin=0,
legend pos=north west,]
\addplot [ycomb,color=black!70] table [col sep=comma,trim cells=true,y=a] {mwe.csv}; \addlegendentry{a}
\addplot [ycomb,color=black!30] table [col sep=comma,trim cells=true,y=b] {mwe.csv}; \addlegendentry{b}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Inside **PGFPLOTS**, those dates are converted to integers representing "this is the Nth day after D-Day". So it is not possible for **PGFPLOTS** to ignore weekends unless you rewrite the converting system.

Comment: To be specific, you need to redefine `\pgfcalendardatetojulian` so that the internal integers represent "this is the Nth weekday after D-Day". Still you need to redefine `\pgfcalendarjuliantodate` to make them a pair of inverse function.

Comment: Another possibility could be to draw the plot with plot with `symbolic x coords`, but then of course *every* bar should have his own label. Otherwise It would be hard to guess which date the non-labeled bars would represent. But because of the number of bars, that would not look good. Actually, I would let everything as is.